# How do I do something like a 'child-added' event in Firebase Cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to get the newly pushed child for a path (/foo) from Firebase realtime database using Cloud Functions.

`/foo
  --newpushKey
     - eeee
     - ffff
  --pushKey1
     - cccc
     - dddd
  --pushkey2
     - aaaa
     - bbbb`

I need only the newly added data ie,

`--newpushKey
     - eeee
     - ffff`

I have gone through https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events. How can I get only the newly added Child from `ref('/foo').onWrite(...)` ?

Or, should I be using the Admin SDK to query `/foo` orderByKey or orderByChild on a timestamp value, with a `limitToLast(1)` ?

Or, does using Sets to do something like a [Set Difference operation](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-set-operations.html) on `snapshot.after.val()` and `snapshot.before.val()` work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to use `onCreate` for newly pushed objects rather than `onWrite` which will trigger on created, updated or deleted objects.

> You can specify a path component as a wildcard by surrounding it with
>   curly brackets;

You need to use a wild card path in the database reference like so:

```
exports.checkForNew = functions.database.ref('foo/{createdID}').onCreate((created_child, context) => {

//context.params.createdID to reference the ID of the created object in the database under 'foo'
//created_child.val() to reference any field values of the created objcet

});
```

Comment: Wildcard path was what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @TroyMyers, Hi, If i need to trigger let's say  ` - eeee:changedElement ` 
How can i do this?

Comment: For more details,  https://i.imgur.com/BJUABEj.png     I want to trigger if the status changed I wanna do something in cloud function like "push notifications" @TroyMyers

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, you even found [the relevant documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) on your own... On that page, take a look at the very last example, I've taken that example and edited it some to make it clearer for you:

```
                                                     Notice this parameter?
                                                     This function will only fire on
                                                     the new data-node itself, not on
                                                     the parent node...
                                                              \/
                                                              \/
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}')
    .onCreate( (change, context) => {

      // Since the function will only fire on the newly created node itself
      // the data that is 'after' the event will be your new data.
      // You can access the new data by calling:
      change.after.val()

      // From here you can do whatever actions you want with that data. 
      // You can access the {pushId} parameter with:
      context.params.pushId

    });
```

Comment: I had failed to notice {pushId}. It makes sense now. Thanks